# compilation failed for package ‘maps’

Tags: r, package

I need to install the package called "maps" to do my homework, but for some reason R Studio will not install it. I can install other packages just fine but only for this one it will not work.

I have restarted my computer and reinstalled R Studio but I am still receiving the following errors when I do install.packages("maps"):

```
> install.packages("maps")
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/maps_3.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2493744 bytes (2.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.4 MB

* installing *source* package ‘maps’ ...
** package ‘maps’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makefile
** libs
** arch - 
make -f "/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/etc/Makeconf" -f Makefile init.o mapclip.o mapget.o smooth.o thin.o 
make[1]: Entering directory '/private/var/folders/8t/1n8nkn2j17x0klpcy58dts180000gn/T/RtmpxTKicW/R.INSTALL1d0156a5fd24/maps/src'
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I"/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c init.c -o init.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I"/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c mapclip.c -o mapclip.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I"/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c mapget.c -o mapget.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I"/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c smooth.c -o smooth.o
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -I"/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c thin.c -o thin.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/private/var/folders/8t/1n8nkn2j17x0klpcy58dts180000gn/T/RtmpxTKicW/R.INSTALL1d0156a5fd24/maps/src'
"/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/R" CMD SHLIB -o maps.dylib init.o mapclip.o mapget.o smooth.o thin.o 
make[1]: Entering directory '/private/var/folders/8t/1n8nkn2j17x0klpcy58dts180000gn/T/RtmpxTKicW/R.INSTALL1d0156a5fd24/maps/src'
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/lib -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/lib -L/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/lib -o maps.dylib init.o mapclip.o mapget.o smooth.o thin.o -L/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/lib -lR -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
make[1]: Leaving directory '/private/var/folders/8t/1n8nkn2j17x0klpcy58dts180000gn/T/RtmpxTKicW/R.INSTALL1d0156a5fd24/maps/src'
make -f "/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/etc/Makeconf" -f Makefile Gmake
make[1]: Entering directory '/private/var/folders/8t/1n8nkn2j17x0klpcy58dts180000gn/T/RtmpxTKicW/R.INSTALL1d0156a5fd24/maps/src'
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/59b7f007-fada-42cf-7435-5bbd0518eaa4/volume/r-base_1570124919999/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/include -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs  -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/lib -L/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/lib  Gmake.c   -o Gmake
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x2D 0x2D 0x2D 0x20 0x21 0x74 0x61 0x70 0x69 0x2D 0x74 0x62 0x64 0x2D 0x76 0x33 ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___sprintf_chk", referenced from:
      _to_ascii in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "___stack_chk_fail", referenced from:
      _to_ascii in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "___stack_chk_guard", referenced from:
      _to_ascii in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "___stderrp", referenced from:
      _fatal in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
      _fatal2 in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_atoi", referenced from:
      _getpoly in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_calloc", referenced from:
      _to_ascii in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
      _to_binary in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_exit", referenced from:
      _fatal in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
      _fatal2 in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
      _main in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_fgetc", referenced from:
      _getpoly in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
      _getword in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_fopen", referenced from:
      _main in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_fprintf", referenced from:
      _fatal in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
      _fatal2 in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
      _to_ascii in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_fputc", referenced from:
      _fatal in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
      _fatal2 in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
      _to_ascii in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_fputs", referenced from:
      _to_ascii in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_fread", referenced from:
      _set_range in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
      _get_lh in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
      _to_ascii in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_fscanf", referenced from:
      _main in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_fseek", referenced from:
      _set_range in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
      _get_lh in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
      _to_ascii in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
      _to_binary in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_ftell", referenced from:
      _to_binary in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_fwrite", referenced from:
      _to_binary in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_isspace", referenced from:
      _getpoly in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
      _getword in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_strcmp", referenced from:
      _getpoly in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
  "_strlen", referenced from:
      _to_ascii in Gmake-e1dfa8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [<builtin>: Gmake] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/private/var/folders/8t/1n8nkn2j17x0klpcy58dts180000gn/T/RtmpxTKicW/R.INSTALL1d0156a5fd24/maps/src'
make: *** [Makefile:58: gmake] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘maps’
* removing ‘/Users/taldunne/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/library/maps’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘maps’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/8t/1n8nkn2j17x0klpcy58dts180000gn/T/RtmpxAfI2b/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: similar looking question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59082237/unable-to-compile-package-maps

Comment: Yes, I found that question. It was solved by reinstalling R-Studio, but unfortunately that did not work for me, so I am posting to try and get more help on the matter.